# Stopping an Unloaded event in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls

I think this isn't the best way to go about doing this but this is the only way I can think of.

I have this WPF UserControl and it is called via a menu item (click on the menu and open the UserControl).

There are a number of things the user can do on the UserControl and I keep track of the changes made (via EF and a variable that is set to true if the user makes any changes).

Now comes the part where I know I'm doing wrongly. I want the UserControl to check if there have been changes or additions made.

I have placed this in the Unloaded event trigger.

```
Private Sub TheUserControl_Unloaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Unloaded
    If (changesMade) Then
        Dim answer = MessageBox.Show("Changes have been.....", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel)

        If (answer = MessageBoxResult.OK) Then
            If (saveChanges() = False) Then
                'stop unloading???
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Discarding changes.")
        End if
    End if
End Sub
```

I realised that I have placed this in the wrong EventControl but I have no idea which Event Control to place it in.

So now I'm asking, where can I put this "check" to ensure that if the user navigates away from this page (by clicking on another item in the menu) they will be asked to save the changes made before the UserControl closes and if an error occurs in the saving, it would stop the UserControl from Unloading.

Thanks.

Comment: placing the code somewhere you are going to switch to the other user control. I think there is no way to stop this event from finishing if you place the code in `Unloaded` event handler.

Comment: You can put a validation method in the UC and then call it from your window when you want to navigate away.  If the method returns `False`, notify the user that they can't leave.

Comment: @KingKing I have thought about that but there are a lot of UC in the menu and a lot of them are not under my control.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Can you explain more about navigate away. It there a Event for that?

Comment: Thank you smarty pants for that unenlightened comment which not only didn't help but didn't even hit anywhere near the mark. Now I can understand why a lot of my peers don't bother with this site. It is because there are people like you that think they know everything and everyone else are just idiots.